# angular ui router $stateParams giving "//"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('cahonas.static_page', {
    url: '*url',
    templateUrl: '/static/templates/cahonas/static_pages/static_page.html',
    controller: 'StaticPageCtrl',
    resolve: {
        metaTags: function (metaTagsResource, $stateParams) {
            return metaTagsResource.get({
                page_name: $stateParams.url.replace("//","")
            }).$promise;
        },
        page: function (staticPageResource, $stateParams) {
            return staticPageResource.get({
                url: $stateParams.url.replace("//","")
            }).$promise;
        }
    }


.factory('staticPageResource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/web/static_page/:url/');
})
```

this is my code so far. keep bumping into "//" which resolves into error and i cant figure it out. does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of dependency module you include in module declaration point (`ngResource` and `angular-ui-router`).

In declaration of factory use strict depedency injection. In configuration area its hard to find problem because it was not throw any error.

```
app.factroy('staticPageResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/web/static_page/:url/');
}]);
```

And also try with rename state name by removing `.`

Comment: thanks for answer mate, but only way i could get it work is to use 0.2.11 ui router with .slice(1).slice(0,-1) rather than replace. 
maybe its wrong with static pages html directions but since its working im not gonna mess around more